# In Jclouds for openstack while creating NeutronApi object it throws com.google.inject.ConfigurationException

Tags: java, guice, openstack, jclouds

I am using jclouds version : 1.8.0-SNAPSHOT

My code snippet is as follows :

```
String provider = "openstack-nova";
String identity = "admin:admin"; // tenantName:userName
String credential = "admin123";
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("jclouds.relax-hostname", "true");
prop.setProperty("jclouds.trust-all-certs", "true");

neutronApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
                .endpoint("http://192.168.95.144:5000/v2.0")
                .credentials(identity, credential)
                .modules(modules).overrides(prop)
                .buildApi(NeutronApi.class);
```

The exception thrown is as follows :

Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.neutron.v2_0.NeutronApi was bound.
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.neutron.v2_0.NeutronApi

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildApi(ContextBuilder.java:654)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildApi(ContextBuilder.java:646)
    at JCloudsNova.(JCloudsNova.java:87)
    at JCloudsNova.main(JCloudsNova.java:43)

Can somebody help me in resolving this

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: Have you provided a binding for NeutronApi in your Guice module?

Comment: No, How can it be done ?

Comment: That is what the error message indicates.  I don't know, but you should be able to look through the examples to see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
String provider = "openstack-neutron";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Everett Toews

Comment: I get the same exception when I have the provider as openstack-neutron.
This is the tutorial I fallowed https://gist.github.com/everett-toews/8701756. I am trying this in a Icehouse Openstack version